# how to increase the volume by trigger

Tags: android

I need to know how to do this in a 2d game 
when my 2d character approaches a sounding spirit. the sound should increase as you approach it and decrease as you move away from it.
for example, it is a radio sprite and makes sounds, and when you approach the radio the sound becomes louder and vice versa.
please help me

Comment: What technology stack are you using? Unity C#? Java? etc. How do you represent and move your character and spirits so far? How have you tried playing sound so far?

Comment: I program in the language c # I interact the character with other objects through tag player scripts. I created this script just to make the music sing when the character enters the collider box 
public class TrigerSFX : MonoBehaviour
{
    public AudioSource PlaySound;

    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag == "Player")
        {
            PlaySound.Play();
        }
            
    }
}

Comment: Looks like you're using Unity. You've probably noticed that code is not very legible in a comment. Please **edit your question** to ensure it contains a complete description of your problem and how you're tackling it so far.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get this behavior is using an [Audio listener](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AudioListener.html) component attached to your player and an [Audio source](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-AudioSource.html) component attached to whatever you want to be making noise. You may want to remove the Audio listener component attached to the camera when you put one on your player.